# Creating a scatter plot from a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am attempting to create a scatter plot from a data frame which alone I can do however with some modifications I cannot get it to work.

my data frame is as follows.

|  | 1s | 2s | 1min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 Jan 18 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.3 |
| 3 Jan 18 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| 4 Jan 18 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.1 |

What I would like to create is a scatter plot of the average of each time interval (sec/min) plotted against the time interval in seconds.

In my data frame I have time intervals up to 30mins.

I know I could add the mean to another data frame and adjust the time intervals in mins to seconds separately, however is there a shorter way to do this that's not hardcoding variables?

I assume that .mean() will calculate the column means which satisfies the first condition but I am unsure of a short way to convert the minuets to seconds within the plt.scatter() code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does `sec/min` mean here?

Comment: sec/min is the column names which some are in seconds 1s, and some are in minuets 30 mins. and the desired output graph would show the x axis in seconds so 30 min would be 1800 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution;

```
Xav = dataframe.mean() #to get the mean across the days 

Xav.index
time = [0] +[pd.Timedelta(x).total_seconds() for x in Xav.index[1:]]
#to convert the columns into seconds 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=0,figsize=(20,4))
sns.scatterplot(x=time,y=Xav,ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_xlabel('Sampling frequency (secs)')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Averaged X')
```